# feign client Spring boot

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-feign-client

```
@FeignClient(name = "usermanagement-service", url = "${application.config.user.url}")
public interface UserClient {

@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addNewUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid InternalUserDto user,@RequestParam MultipartFile image);

}

   public Object saveInternalUsers(@ModelAttribute InternalUserDto user,@Nullable MultipartFile file) {
        return userClient.addNewUser(user,file).getBody();
    }
```

I am getting null when user is get into addNewUser in userClient userClient.addNewUser(user,file).getBody(); how to solve this issue

I need to save the internaluserDto data using feignClient springboot

Comment: The pairing of your burly brackets seems strange

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.